# Plugin to report when site becomes unavailable

Tags: server

I have a Craft installation on DigitalOcean, with the smallest package:

```
512MB Memory
1 Core Processor
20GB SSD Disk
1TB Transfer
```

I installed the default LAMP droplet.

PROBLEM:
MySQL crashes from time to time. There were no significant server load either.

What might be a root cause?

**Bonus question:**

Is there a plugin that automatically reports when the site is down?

[image]

Comment: Question is still open, when Craft crashes gracefully, I would assume it to fire a hook event. Note that crash can mean a faulty MySQL connection too, but for the visitors it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

There's no plugin for that... it wouldn't quite make sense. If the site went down, the plugin would be down too.

Your best bet is to find a 3rd party service to monitor the site's uptime. There are several services which will alert (via text or email) if your site becomes unavailable. Here are a few examples...

- [Uptime Robot](https://uptimerobot.com/)
- [New Relic](https://newrelic.com/)
- [Pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com/)

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense :) Uptime robot monitoring is already installed for that site and I haven't reveived an alert. Maybe server is not serving 500 code? I haven't tested it, because of putting off fire.

Comment: FWIW [Constellix Sonar](http://constellix.com/sonar/sonarchecks/) can also be useful because it'll capture traceroutes from its nodes that report issues. Also free for some undefined amount of time.

Comment: Thanks, I already use some similar solution on another project.

Is there an onError hook for craft? If it can display a nice maintenance page, I'm sure it can send and error report before :)

Comment: @TiborSzasz No `onError` hook. Craft has some internal logic to serve `{errorCode}.html` templates for internal exceptions, but if your database burns down and someone hacks into your server and uninstalls Apache obviously that stuff goes out the window. Like Lindsey says, use a third party service to monitor uptime, and possibly a third party service like [Rollbar](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/rollbar) to monitor exceptions.

Comment: Sure, but it would be handy. Uptime Robot didn't catch the 503 error that goes with faulty DB connection. I should check out other services.

Comment: @MatsMikkelRummelhoff if you post the no hook as answer I accept it.

Comment: @MatsMikkelRummelhoff Craft doesn't explicitly define an onError event because Yii already provides one (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#onError-detail) as well as onException (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#onException-detail)

Comment: Thats good to know, @BradBell - wasnt aware of that.